# how to loop over two array's but saving execution time as much as possible

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

I have two arrays **array a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]** and **array b = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]** and i am returning a array list which contains a count where i taking elements of **array b** and checking what elements of **array a** are greater than or equal to the each element of **array b**, and i am storing this in **count** varible and later adding each **count** to the list so the output will be **list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]**, but the code i've written is lacking in the performance for larger sets of input and not giving supposed answer's in the expected way any idea of how can i improve my code to improve the performance

```
static List<Integer> giantArmy(int a[],int b[]){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (a.length == 1 && a[0] == 0) {
            list.add(0);
            return list;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] >= b[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            list.add(count);
            count = 0;
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Sort the array being searched, then use `Arrays.binarySearch`. If you want to optimize further, sort the source array too, then as you iterate remember the results of the previous search to restrict the next search to a subset of the array being searched, using `fromIndex` &  `toIndex` in `binarySearch` call.

Comment: no arrays are not sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation of Basil Bourque's comment.
This is `O(n log n)`. (Sort is `O(n log n)` and binary search `O(log n)` repeated `n` times)

```
static List<Integer> giantArmy(int a[],int b[]){
    int aLength = a.length;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (int i : b) {
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(a, i);
        if (index < 0)
            index = -index - 1;
        result.add(aLength - index);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(giantArmy(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, new int[] {6, 5, 4, 3, 2}));
}
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A binary search of `n` for the sorted `a` yields the number of elements of `a` whose number of elements to the right of the position found is greater than or equal to `n`.

```
[1 2 3 4 5]
                (number of elements >= 6) = 0
         x      (number of elements >= 5) = 1
       x x      (number of elements >= 4) = 2
     x x x      (number of elements >= 3) = 3
   x x x x      (number of elements >= 2) = 4
 x x x x x      (number of elements >= 1) = 5
 x x x x x      (number of elements >= 0) = 5
```

Comment: can you explain in brief how binary search worked in this problem ?

Comment: @NeelChavan Updated my answer.  Sorry, I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<Integer> giantArmy(Integer a[],Integer b[]){
    TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<>();
    List<Integer> aList = Arrays.asList(a);

    ts.addAll(aList);
    Integer[] count = new Integer[b.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        Set<Integer> tail_set = ts.tailSet(b[i]);
  
        count[i] = tail_set.size();
    }

    return Arrays.asList(count);
    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```